# How do I check if an array of objects is empty/null?

Tags: c++, arrays, object

Lets say I have an object array declared like this:

```
Object Array[100];
int count = 0;
bool exit;

do
{
    if (Array[count] == "")
    {
        //code that stores data
        exit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}
while (exit != true);
```

I keep having errors from the compiler which says:

```
error: no match for ‘operator==’ in ‘Array[count] == ""'
```

I know I can use a for loop function to store them correctly or even use a vector, but for now, I have to use this method to check if the array is empty/null. Any idea how to do it? I have seen many examples here, but almost all of it are string/int/float etc etc arrays.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The array itself cannot be "empty".

```
Object Array[100];
```

is a declaration that creates an array of 100 `Object`s. They are already constructed and present (if default constructible).

If the type `Object` has some notion of an "empty" state you could check for that (A `std::vector` for example provides the member `.empty()` to check for emptyness.) or you can use a container to hold your data (which also makes it part of the heap instead of the stack memory and enables dynamic resizing).

```
std::vector<Object> vec;
int count = 0;
// do stuff...
do
{
    if (count >= vec.size())
    {
        //code that stores data
        exit = true;
    }
    else
    {
        count++;
    }
}
while (exit != true);
```

Whereas you could also say `std::size_t count = vec.size();`.

Comment: Ok, i did a bit of research on vector and manage to convert my arrays to vector, but after i hit compile, i face the problem whereby the compiler tells me there is no member named empty. I was using !vec[0].empty() to check if the vector is empty or not.

Comment: `vec.empty()` tells you if the `vector` itself is empty. `vec[0].empty()` is two expressions and calls `empty()` on the first element of the vector. Therefore the conent type of the vector needs to support `empty()`. If you want a structure that can have a filled element 6 but empty element 4 you need to go for one more level of indirection (pointers or smart pointers for example).

Comment: Meaning i cant just use the `.empty` itself ? cause i have a loop function that works something like `vec[count].empty()`. Then everytime it does the check and if all is fine, it will `count++` and go to the next location to check.

Comment: If you want the number of elements in the vector just use `vector.size()`.

Answer (score 1):

When you created the array using: `Object Array[100];` it **already created** 100 memory slots for your `Object`s, and called the default constructor for each one of them.

- Physically, there are 100 elements in your array right after the quoted line.
- Logically, there are as much as you decide, and its best you save that number to `count`.

---

If the `Object`'s default c'tor is not enough in terms of initialization, then you have several options for checking weather it's content is initialized or not:

- you can add a method (i.e. `bool isInitialized()`)
- you can add an `operator==` that takes `const char *` as an argument and compare it to `""`.
- you can add an `operator==` that takes another `Object` as an argument and compare it to `""` assuming `Object` has a c'tor from `const char *`.

Answer (score 0):

`Object Array[100];` cannot be empty. On the other hand, pointer to dynamically allocated array can be initialized to nullptr and checked against that:

```
Object *Array = nullptr;

if(!Array) // or Array == nullptr
    cout << "Array is empty (unallocated)" << endl;

Array = new Array[100];

if(Array) // or Array != nullptr
    cout << "Array is NOT empty" << endl;
```

`Array[count]` doesn't make sense. you are accessing element at index `count` (which is a bad name for index) and comparing that with `const char*`. `std::vector` is the way to go. Code above (and everything other than using `std::vector`) - ugly and bad practice.